# Python - Check if part of element is in set

Tags: python

I have a set with this output:

```
 set( [Rule(chain='OUTPUT', num='3', pkts='0', bytes='0', target='ACCEPT', prot='tcp', opt='--', inp='*', out='*', source='0.0.0.0/0', destination='10.10.7.84', extra='tcp spt:7390'), 
 Rule(chain='INPUT', num='1', pkts='0', bytes='0', target='ACCEPT', prot='tcp', opt='--', inp='*', out='*', source='148.100.0.0/16', destination='0.0.0.0/0', extra='tcp dpt:7390'), 
 Rule(chain='INPUT', num='3', pkts='0', bytes='0', target='ACCEPT', prot='tcp', opt='--', inp='*', out='*', source='10.10.7.84', destination='0.0.0.0/0', extra='tcp dpt:7390')])
```

I want to check if an element matches an item in this set, but disregarding

```
num='', pkts='', bytes=''
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This depends a lot on the `Rule` class and how it's `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods are implemented.  Unless `Rule.__hash__` and `Rule.__eq__` disregard the `num`, `pkts` and `bytes` fields,  you'll have to loop through all the `Rule` instances in the set until you find one that is matching.

Comment: Does `Rule(x,y,z) in set(Rule(x,y,z))` not work?

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, but this is one way of going about it. If this rule should extend to any kind of equality check, I advise modifying the magic `__eq__(self, other)` method of the `Rule` class with the `rules_match` logic.

```
def rules_match(rule1, rule2):
    attributes_to_check = ['chain', 'target', 'prot', 'opt', ...]
    return all(getattr(rule1, attribute) == getattr(rule2, attribute) for attribute in attributes_to_check)

def rule_in_set(rule, rule_set):
    return any(rules_match(rule, i) for i in rule_set)
```

Comment: Is there a way to return true or false in rule_in_set that doesn't involve modifying the method?

Comment: @mariahm24 Not sure what you mean. Modify what method?

Comment: Sorry, just started looking at python this week, not very familiar with it. If I set any(rules_match(rule, i) for i in rule_set) to a variable, and check if the variable is empty and return false, else return true, will that work?

Comment: `any` returns a boolean value `True` or `False`. So yes, you can set a variable using it, i.e. `rule_is_in_set = any(rules_match(rule, i) for i in rule_set)`